# DATEDIFF with cutoff time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I'm working on a Room Scheduling application. We have this Room Check Out Rule that we need follow. All 
room check out should be 12:00 PM. If the check out date is after 12.00 PM it will be considered additional 1 day.

Below is my T-SQL code that returns 5 days.

```
  SELECT DATEDIFF(day, '3/12/2013 12:00:00 PM', '3/17/2013 3:00:00 PM');
```

If you see the code above the end date is 3:00:00 PM. How can I tweak this code to return 6 days instead of 5?

What if I have this code?

```
  SELECT CEILING(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '3/12/2013 02:00:00 PM' , '3/17/2013 12:50:36 PM') / (24.0 * 60 * 60))
```

The above code still returns 5 days instead of 6.

Comment: 12:00 PM is Noon not Midnight. Have you stated the problem correctly?

Comment: Yes it 12:00PM Noon time. The rule is Check Out Time should always be 12:00PM.

Comment: The start date is not important. The company rule is all room check out above 12:00 PM must add 1 day. I know it's weird but that's the rule they gave me. :-(

Comment: my bad. In order for me to have consistent results I decided to put 12:00 PM in the start date. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way is to subtract 12 hours from StartDate and EndDate, then take a day-diff + 1:

```
declare @dateStart as datetime, @dateEnd as datetime
set @dateStart = cast('20130301 11:59:59 AM' as datetime)
set @dateEnd   = cast('20130301 12:01:01 PM' as datetime)

select 
  @dateStart, 
  @dateEnd

select days = 1 + datediff(d,@dateStart,@dateEnd)

select 
  days = 1 + datediff(d, dateadd(hh, -12, @dateStart), dateadd(hh, -12, @dateEnd))
```

returns this:

```
----------------------- -----------------------
2013-03-01 11:59:59.000 2013-03-01 12:01:01.000

days
-----------
1

days
-----------
2
```

Clearly the second formula is correct, not the first.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CEILING(DATEDIFF(SECOND, '3/12/2013 12:00:00 PM', '3/17/2013 12:00:01 PM') / (24.0 * 60 * 60))
```

Comment: Fastastic! Thanks @polybios

Comment: @user2059064 Count hours and divide to 24.

Comment: @polybios CEILING what is main use of this

Comment: @A.Goutam read the docs, man. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189818.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the code @polybios. I now have a solution. I'll just put a standard start date with 12:00 PM time to get consistent results.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can count hours:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(hour, '3/12/2013 12:00:00 PM', '3/17/2013 3:00:00 PM');
```

Therefore, `123 > 120` (or divided by 24 - `5.125 > 5`) accounts for 6 days.